# A very peculiar problem with an old pc and a newer laptop

Tags: networking, ethernet, freebsd

I got my old pc ( 248mb ram , 80 GB ) repaired and the tech people put XP in it. My newer laptop has UBUNTU 10.04 .now I only have one cable and one usb cord .So I connected my modem (with only one CAT5 port and 4 usb ports ) to laptop with CAT5 cable . The internet is working fine .

I also wanted to use net on older pc so I installed the usb drivers for Windows and it worked.

But I got fed up of Windows XP and made a separate partition for FreeBSD which I planned to install. During the install I screwd up sumthing and now freebsd starts with a boot option with a ? mark in place of win xp .If I click on that it gives me a `NTLDR missing` msg.

I tried connecting CAT5 cable between old and new pc and tried connecting my laptop with USB cable but nothing happend and then I realized the modem doesn`t have a WORKING usb driver for LINUX :(  FreeBSD doesn't even detect the LAN cable if I use it for old pc .

So basically I have a old pc that has FreeBSD which I can only start and stare at the blank terminal console but works perfectly otherwise. FreeBSD was supposed to detect the LAN cable. And I have a laptop that has LINUX which only works if I connect it with a CAT5 cable .

So what can I do with my old pc ? Any local server (if possible :( ) or some such thing ? or can u suggest any use ?

Comment: Strange. I thought that it would have used the `cdc_ether` driver.

Comment: You need a cheap unmanaged "switch" so you can connect all PCs to the modem using cat5....http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100010066%204024&IsNodeId=1&name=$0%20-%20$10

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Windows XP boot loader got mangled by the FreeBSD install.  You might be able to fix it by booting the old PC from a WinXP CD or boot floppy.  See the Microsoft page [Microsoft support page here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318728) or [this page](http://www.tinyempire.com/notes/ntldrismissing.htm), or others found by Googling your "NTLDR missing" message.

Once you get that fixed, go find yourself a cheap network switch for making your network connection available to more than one computer.  Trying to patch together funky connections through USB or point-to-point network connections can quickly lead to madness.